# Difference between mobile application and web application?

Tags: automated-testing, manual-testing, test-management

Why we use mobile app rather than web app?
It's a common question answered by many websites but I did not find my answer.
Please make your answer short and specific. Real life example.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because its not about testing or quality assurance.

Answer (score 1):

A mobile app is a program that is downloaded and installed onto a user's mobile device, whereas a mobile website is simply a website adapted to tablet and smartphone formats.

Please check these [link](https://www.unitag.io/mobile-websites/what-is-the-difference-between-a-mobile-application-and-a-mobile-webpage) and [link](https://www.apteligent.com/2015/09/app-insight-between-mobile-and-web/) for more details.

Comment: I don't think that's what Mehul is asking for. He didn't ask for a difference between Mobile App and a website.

Comment: Yes, Difference between Mobile App and a website. One company is asking question.

Answer (score 1):

Web application takes more time to load pages and there are also performance issues whereas mobile apps are much faster than Web application. Hence, mobile app usage is more than Web app.